# Uses of Interface accessed in many way?

Tags: java, interface

I am learning of interface in java while i access it in my sub class main method i can access in three way what are the difference of those am learner could some one help  on this

```
public interface interfa
{
    void educationloan();
    abstract void homeloan();
    static int i = 10;;

}
public class testinter  implements interfa {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println("Sub class access a interface by implement");

        testinter t = new testinter();
        t.miniloan();
        t.educationloan();
        t.homeloan();

        System.out.println("Super class access a only interface in sub class");

        interfa a = new testinter();
        a.educationloan();
        //a.miniloan();
        a.homeloan();

        System.out.println("Annomys class access a only interface in sub class");

        interfa xx = new interfa() {

            @Override
            public void homeloan() {
            }
            @Override
            public void educationloan() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };


        xx.educationloan();
        xx.homeloan();

    }
}
```

Here my question comes which one can use in which situation and what are the difference???

Answer (score 1):

First thing you will get a compile time error big time as you haven't implemented the interface methods in the child class.

```
 testinter t = new testinter();
        t.miniloan(); 
        t.educationloan(); // these methods should be initialized 
        t.homeloan();
```

Now regarding your interface implementation ways:

1. `testinter t = new testinter();`

t is an instance of a child class & can be used like a regular class object.

2. `interfa a = new testinter();`

The upside of using this approach is say you have used the reference `a` n times in your code & in future you want to change the implementation of your interface to `interfa a = new AnotherTestinter();` All you have to do is change the implementation the reference will not be changed. This is loose coupling otherwise you have to change the reference `a` everywhere in the code. This approach is always known as *Programming to an interface.*

3. Using [anonymous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) class

   interfa xx = new interfa() {
               @Override
           public void homeloan() {
           }
           @Override
           public void educationloan() {
               // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           }
       };

Anonymous classes enable you to make your code more concise. They enable you to declare and instantiate a class at the same time. They are like local classes except that they do not have a name. Use them if you need to use a local class only once. 
So doing this `interfa xx = new interfa() {` helps you define your methods `educationloan() homeloan()` at the same place.

Answer (score 0):

1. t itselft is a instance of a child class. it can be used normally like other class objects
2. t is a instance of the interfa. Here t can be used in both cases where either the child or the parent class is needed.
3. in this implementation you have to implement the methods of the interface in your own way. You can implement different things here instead of using the default implementation.

N.B. I overlooked one thing, you will get a compiler error as you haven't implemented the methods of interfa in the child class

Comment: thanks for u r inforamtion here i created a annomys interace and super type access a sub class type it will be same or not